# How to make square corner images in the bootstrap card group

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

using bootstrap 4 card for image gallery

```
<div class="card-group flex-wrap">
                    <div class="card border-dark">
                       <img class="card-img-top" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/03/14/54/rock-formations-5623735__340.jpg"  alt="Card image cap">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card border-dark">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/03/14/54/rock-formations-5623735__340.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card border-dark">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/03/14/54/rock-formations-5623735__340.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                    </div>
</div>
```

but above image gallery is little bit rounded in border-radius. I need square image corners (no border radius) in the gallery. I tryed following one but not sucess here

```
 <img src="" class="img img-responsive full-width" />
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the border `rounded-0` utility class...

```
  <div class="card-group flex-wrap">
        <div class="card border-dark rounded-0">
            <img class="card-img-top rounded-0" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/03/14/54/rock-formations-5623735__340.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        <div class="card border-dark rounded-0">
            <img class="card-img-top rounded-0" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/03/14/54/rock-formations-5623735__340.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
        <div class="card border-dark rounded-0">
            <img class="card-img-top rounded-0" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/03/14/54/rock-formations-5623735__340.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        </div>
  </div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/JtMTY4zb5v)